# Node.js: How to write to the java-childprocess-stdin

Tags: java, node.js, stdin, bukkit, child-process

I've written a node.js-server who could spawn a java childprocess from a webinterface and display the stdout of the jar to the interface. now I need to send some commands over the stdin to the jar and thath's my problem:

I'm spawning the server:

```
jar = cp.spawn('java', ['-Xmx1024M', '-jar', dir+'craftbukkit.jar', '-o true','-nojline'], {
cwd:dir);
```

Trying to send some command:

```
jar.stdin('stop\n');
```

But It doesen't do anything. In Other Childprocesses it worked like this but now i've got no idea how to do this. Anybody an Idea?

Thx Guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `jar`object is a [ChildProcess object](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_class_childprocess), which has three [streams](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html): `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr`. They are not functions, but streams that you can read from (stdout and stderr) and write to (stdin).

Here is an example:

```js
jar.stdin.write('stop\n');
jar.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
```

which will write some data to the standard input of your child process, and pipe its output to the standard output of your Node process (ie. the console).

Note that the [`write()`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_write_chunk_encoding_callback) call is asynchronous: there may be a small delay between the time you called `write()` and the time it is really written to the process input.

For an overview of streams, you can read [The Stream Handbook](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook).